# How to handle nested if conditions in windows batch

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch script with multiple `if` conditions.

- Check if a folder `C:\Apps\WorkingFolder\NewAppln` exists.

  - If it doesn't exist execute a `.jar` from a network drive, `G:`.
  - If it does exist compare a file `CheckDate.log` on both the local drive and network drive.

    - If logs are the same, execute a `.jar` from a network drive, `G:`.
    - If logs are different, rename the existing `folder` to `folder_sysdate` in local, and execute a `.jar` from a network drive, `G:`.

Here is my code

```
@ echo on
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
IF   EXIST  C:\Apps\Workingfolder\NewAppln\  (goto FOUND) else ( goto NOTFOUND)
:EOF

: FOUND
FC C:\Apps\Workingfolder\NewAppln\CheckDate.log   G:\Workingfolder\NewAppln\CheckDate.log | find "***">NUL
    (IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (GOTO SAME) ELSE (GOTO DIFFERENT)
    GOTO :EOF

    :SAME
    @"G:\JRE1.509\bin\java" -jar "loadApp.jar"
    START /D"C:\Apps\Workingfolder\NewAppln" MyApp.exe
    GOTO :EOF

    :DIFFERENT
    move C:\Apps\Workingfolder\NewAppln C:\Apps\Workingfolder\NewAppln_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%-%DATE:/=% 
    @"G:\JRE1.509\bin\java" -jar "loadApp.jar"
    START /D"C:\Apps\Workingfolder\NewAppln" MyApp.exe
    )
:EOF

:NOTFOUND
cd G:\Workingfolder\NewAppln_WIN10\
@"G:\JRE1.509\bin\java" -jar "loadApp.jar"
START /D"C:\Apps\Workingfolder\NewAppln" MyApp.exe
```

Comment: There are flaws in your code, [syntax IF](http://Ss64.com/nt/if.html), No lables inside (code blocks) and  several more...

Comment: Can you please advise  on how the correction can be made

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo on
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
IF EXIST "C:\Apps\Workingfolder\NewAppln\" (goto FOUND) else goto NOTFOUND
GOTO :EOF

: FOUND
FC "C:\Apps\Workingfolder\NewAppln\CheckDate.log" "G:\Workingfolder\NewAppln\CheckDate.log | find "***" >NUL
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (GOTO SAME) ELSE GOTO DIFFERENT
GOTO :EOF

:SAME
@"G:\JRE1.509\bin\java" -jar "loadApp.jar"
START "" /D "C:\Apps\Workingfolder\NewAppln" MyApp.exe
GOTO :EOF

:DIFFERENT
move "C:\Apps\Workingfolder\NewAppln" "C:\Apps\Workingfolder\NewAppln_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%-%DATE:/=%"
@"G:\JRE1.509\bin\java" -jar "loadApp.jar"
START "" /D "C:\Apps\Workingfolder\NewAppln" MyApp.exe
GOTO :EOF

:NOTFOUND
cd "G:\Workingfolder\NewAppln_WIN10\"
@"G:\JRE1.509\bin\java" -jar "loadApp.jar"
START "" /D "C:\Apps\Workingfolder\NewAppln" MyApp.exe
```

You do not create labels named `:EOF` as `goto` treats `:EOF` as ***E***nd **O**f **F**ile.

Use of parentheses was unneeded in some areas so removed them.

Done minor cleanup and added some double quotes with some paths.

It is usually a good idea to specify a title for `start` so it does not
cause issues as the first set of double quotes can be taken as the title
whether you like it or not.

Comment: Very tangled code. Using of `goto` should be minimized for the sake of readability and better understanding.

Comment: why not simply move the code into the code blocks, instead of the `goto` statements?

Answer (score 0):

Refactored the code a little. Although there's a lot of room for improvement (especially these blocks with Java launching).

```
@echo on
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
IF EXIST C:\Apps\Workingfolder\NewAppln\ (
   FC C:\Apps\Workingfolder\NewAppln\CheckDate.log  G:\Workingfolder\NewAppln\CheckDate.log | find "***">NUL
   IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
      @"G:\JRE1.509\bin\java" -jar "loadApp.jar"
      START /D"C:\Apps\Workingfolder\NewAppln" MyApp.exe
   ) else (
      move C:\Apps\Workingfolder\NewAppln C:\Apps\Workingfolder\NewAppln_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%-%DATE:/=% 
      @"G:\JRE1.509\bin\java" -jar "loadApp.jar"
      START /D"C:\Apps\Workingfolder\NewAppln" MyApp.exe
   )
) else (
   cd G:\Workingfolder\NewAppln_WIN10\
   @"G:\JRE1.509\bin\java" -jar "loadApp.jar"
   START /D"C:\Apps\Workingfolder\NewAppln" MyApp.exe
)
```

BTW `NOTFOUND` part will not work as expected since the script will get there when the folder `C:\Apps\Workingfolder\NewAppln` is not exist but the command line `START /D"C:\Apps\Workingfolder\NewAppln" MyApp.exe` does explicitly use it.

Comment: Bringing the multiple `C:\Apps\Workingfolder\NewAppln`s out as  `SET "APPPATH=C:\Apps\Workingfolder\NewAppln"` might help (especially if it ever changes).

Comment: @TripeHound Completely agree. There's a lot that could be improved but the question from OP was about `if` nesting so I've decided to leave additional refactoring as a 'homework' :).

Comment: What changes do you recommend for the jar part ..please advise .I will try to work on that

Comment: @zainab.july2019 If you'll look closely then you'll understand that parts with java.exe and start of MyApp.exe are executed in the end of every possible condition tree. That means you could exclude them out of the conditions and put after.